# change background color from top to bottom

Tags: css, animation

I have a div that has a white background color.

Now I am wondering if it is possible to change the backgroundcolor on hover with an animation form top top bottom. Just like the color comes over the white.

I know this can be done with an image, but can I do it without?

Comment: set a gradient that is bigger than your div, and that changes from white to the color outside the visible part. Then animate the background position. If you know how to do it with an image, you shouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can animate gradients in CSS3. There is a tutorial [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/).